# Sass apply css to media query and class in same time

Tags: css, sass

I use Sass and I want to apply some style with two conditions

first if media query < desktop 
second if the container have class "affiliations"

How can I wrote it without duplicate the style

I try the following but its not work

```
  @include media ('<desktop'),.affiliations {

  .search
   {
    color:red;
    .icon{
      color: blue;
    }.........etc
  }

}
```

Comment: Breakpoints for sass http://breakpoint-sass.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can't be done with only sass, usually you would structure your code like this

```
.someclass {
  color: deepskyblue;

  @media (max-width: 1023) {
    .affiliations & {
      color: deeppink;
    }
  }
}
```